# skype: no mic under kde

Tags: 12.04, sound, skype, microphone

It seems that I can use my mic under gnome, but not under kde.

There must be a setting somewhere under KDE that will allow me to use the mic that is built into my web cam, but I can't find it anywhere.

How can I make use of my microphone under KDE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to System Settings. Click on Multimedia. Click on Phonon.

There is a list of categories on the left side of the window. Click on the following options: Audio recording, Communication, Recording, Control (the last three are under the "Audio Recording" section which is a category itself). Move your device to the top of the list and click Apply.

Then make sure your microphone is unmuted: go to the KMix program and click the "Capture devices" tab. Make sure that the speaker icon at the bottom does not have a red X next to it; if it does, click the speaker icon.

Comment: Kmix failed to open. I couldn't open it from the menu or the terminal. However, going through the first part of the process worked.Thank you.